# How to commit from command line to a SVN Google Code repository?

Tags: svn

I know how to checkout but when I try to commit it gives me this message:

```
svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: Server sent unexpected return value (405 Method Not Allowed) in response to 
     MKACTIVITY request for '/svn/!svn/act/25696683-c16a-45c6-9c35-9431e92548ec'
```

Comment: What version of the Subversion client are you using? What command did you use to try to commit? Do you have write permission to the repository?

Comment: My svn cliente version is: svn, version 1.6.15 (r1038135)
I use: svn commit -m 'new feature' --username <myemailaddress>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [goggle code ticket 1916](http://code.google.com/p/support/issues/detail?id=1916) has all the possible causes for this:

> "`405 Method Not Allowed`" usually means you have an HTTP proxy somewhere which is blocking WebDAV HTTP request such as `MKCOL`.
>   The proxy might be on your network or ISP, or it might be built into Windows.
>   Either way, this is a client-side problem (not related to `googlecode.com`), and is best handled by posting to the general svn user-support group at `users@subversion.tigris.org`.

Basically, you need to triple-check your username and password. Also:

> try checking out a fresh **`https://`** working copy for svn-wagon to use.
>   The server certificate changed, and svn-wagon may just be failing because of that 
>   (rather than properly re-prompting you whether to trust the certificate or not.)

Comment: You are right, I was using http:// instead of https:// in my checks, thanks a lot